# Where do I save docker-compose files of a swarm?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, swarm

We are running Docker Swarm + Ceph. All runs okay. We plan to move more of our internally developed as well as third party applications to Swarm. Now the issue I have is as follows:

Let’s say I deployed 10 third party applications as Swarm stacks. I do this with Docker `stack deploy` command. I supply docker-compose file to it (often, in its turn composed out of multiple docker-compose-*.yml files compiled via docker-compose config). Now, if I want to change something in the stack, I often need my initial compose-files. Is there any kind of registry for docker-compose deployment descriptors? Like docker image registry but for docker-compose descriptors?

One of the ideas I have is to maintain Git or Mercurial repository with some directory structure to version the descriptors. This idea looks interesting, but works (semi-)well just for third party applications. With our own applications this adds a problem, as we often use CI/CD. And this would mean that we need to checkout one more repository during deployment, replace deployment descriptors for our apps and commit them. This may be a little tricky, as it may potentially lead to merge conflicts, etc.

Ideally, the solution I am looking for shall provide an easy way to get the latest versions of deployment descriptors of a particular (deployed) stack at the same time holding previous versions of them.

How do you manage your docker-compose files when there are too much of them?

Comment: Looks like a better fit for devops.SE.

Comment: Please try to avoid gender assumptions about software engineers, as it can be unwelcoming. We tend to trim greetings and salutations anyway. Thank you.

Comment: @halfer Oh, thanks for pointing to this. This was (probably) my first post to SO. I will be more neutral in my next posts.